# How to specify credentials for Prometheus pod scrape

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a metrics endpoint `/actuator/prometheus` that is protected by authentication. I have set up a jvm monitoring job on prometheus using below method:

1. add prometheus scrape annotations in my pod config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   ...
  strategy:
   ...
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ...
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/path: "/actuator/prometheus"
        prometheus.io/port: "80"
    spec:
     ...
```

2. add a job `xxx-jvm` under `extraScrapeConfigs` to specify the credentials

```
extraScrapeConfigs: |
 - job_name: 'xxx-jvm'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
    basic_auth:
      username: ...
      password: ...
    relabel_configs:
      ...
```

Then I checked prometheus dashboard `Status` -> `Targets` tab, the `xxx-jvm` has 1 endpoint which shows `up` (the jvm metrics all shows up correctly)
[image]

But in `kubernetes-pods` section, there is a same endpoint that shows `down`, this is causing the alert `up == 0` keep firing
[image]

It looks like the `prometheus.io/scrape: "true"` annotation also added a endpoint in `kubernetes-pods` besides the `xxx-jvm` job, and it does not use the credentials I specified in `xxx-jvm` job config.  How do I specify the credentials for this endpoint in `kubernetes-pods`? Or how can I make it so that `xxx-jvm` job and `kubernetes-pods` use different path?